# Unable to delete data through View class

Tags: php, codeigniter

Currently I have a notes tab in my View class that lets me edit and delete my notes. My edit part works as intended and changes the stuff I change in my View class back in my database as well. But I'm unable to press the delete button for some reason which does't allow me to make a difference in my database.

Currently this is my View class code for both edit and delete:

```
<td>
    <a class="edit text-info" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="save text-info" href="javascript:void(0)" data-url="<?php echo site_url('contacts/updatenote/'.$val['notes_id']) ?>" style="display:none">
        <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
    </a>
</td>
<td>
    <a class="remove text-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" data-url="<?php echo site_url('contacts/deletenote/'.$val['notes_id']) ?>" >
        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
    </a>
</td>

<script>
$('.edit').click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).hide(); var $t=$(this).closest('tr'),content = $t.find('.textnote').html();
    $t.find('.textnote').html('<textarea name="leadnote" class="ntext">' + content + '</textarea>');
    $t.find('textarea.ntext').focus();
    $t.find('.save').show();
}); 
</script>
```

Controller Class:

```
public function deletenote($id)
{
    $c = $this->contacts_model->load($id, "refno");
    echo $this->contacts_model->delete_note($id);       
}
```

Model Class:

```
function delete_note($id)
{
    return $this->db->delete("crm_contacts_notes",array('notes_id'=>$id));
}
```

Comment: To be clear here... Are you saying you cannot PRESS the button OR when you press the button the delete functionality does not remove the row from the table??

Comment: I cannot press the button. So with my update, if I hover over it I get `javascript:void(0)` in the bottom left of my screen, but nothing with delete